# Yii2 console commands not working linux (basic application)

Tags: php, linux, yii2, console, thumbnails

I was trying to add Chiliec/yii2-vote widget to my project. However when I tried to run the migration nothing happens so I tried other commands and they also do nothing [image: Commands in console literally do nothing]

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
[kyle@kyle-pc blog]$ ./yii help
./yii: line 3: ?php: No such file or directory
./yii: line 4: /bin: Is a directory
./yii: line 5: assets: command not found
./yii: line 6: assets: command not found
./yii: line 7: assets: command not found
./yii: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./yii: line 8: ` * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's something wrong with your php cli config because even the `yii help` doesn't have any output.

If you run this command, does return something?

```
php -r "echo 'Hello, world.';"
```

You can try enabling the error messages in your CLI config.ini you can try other tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330620/php-cli-script-does-not-output-anything)

Comment: Yes that returns "Hello, world."

Comment: Try running ```php -d display_errors=1 -f yii
``` to see if there are any errors

Comment: `Warning: require(/srv/http/blog/common/config/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/http/blog/yii on line 16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/srv/http/blog/common/config/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php56/pear') in /srv/http/blog/yii on line 16`

Comment: I have just checked out 'yii' file and its contents are for the advanced application but I have the basic application installed

Comment: In this case I would copy the contents of the ```yii``` file from the basic app template: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/yii

Comment: I have done - commands now work however giving me a list of other errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155601/discussion-between-szanto-zoltan-and-kyle).