# Yii2 console commands not working on centOS

Tags: php, yii2, centos, yii2-advanced-app

I am unable to run yii2 console commands such as php yii cron/action, php yii migrate, etc. on centos server where I deployed the Yii2 application.

I have tried php -d display_errors=1 -f yii as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489808/yii2-console-commands-not-working-linux-basic-application) to see if I will see any error messages but nothing is showing. Kindly assist on how to get this running on a centos server.

Comment: It could help if you state what is happening when you run such commands...

Comment: Nothing is happening. It just shows a blank response like nothing happened. Basically, it is not running those commands for some weird reasons